# Extremely worried about Magento performance

Tags: php, mysql, apache, magento

I currently have 1 magento app running 3 different stores:

- [BelExpress](http://www.belexpress.eu/)
- [Medical em Casa](http://www.medicalemcasa.com/)
- [Medical Express](http://www.medicalexpress.net/index.php) (this one is still under construction)

The database for this store is 370MB in size. The stores share 9.000 SKU's and they have 1k to 2k grouped products (that associate the SKU's) each.

Running the apache AB benchmark tool, I get as low as 0.29 requests per second, which I reckon is a very very low number even for a magento store.

The biggest worry though, is the backend. There are currently 5 people updating and inserting new products through the backend and it's taking as long as 4 minutes to update/insert ONE product. That's a massive waste of time, and I can't for the life of me explain it.

Here are my server's resources:

- Processor: AMD Athlon X2 3400+ (2x 1.8Ghz)
- Memory: 4GB
- Disks: 2x 500Gb

I'm running Debian Lenny Apache 2.0, PHP Version 5.2.6-1+lenny16 with eAccelerator and Memcahed. (you can check all the info [here](http://www.medicalemcasa.com/phpinfo.php))

And here are my config files for Apache, MySQL and PHP.

- [Apache](http://pastebin.com/F6cEHBPp)
- [MySQL](http://pastebin.com/h7x5SsUx)
- [PHP](http://pastebin.com/a12nA63Y)

I'm not a server admin (although I'm responsible for all the websites and server itself), so this is not my "beach" so to speak. My question is, is this the way it's supposed to work with my current resources, or am I missing something important in my configuration?

I realize this may seem like I'm looking for "hand helding" but that's not my intention. I'm simply tired of trying new stuff over and over and I just can't seem to make it run smoothly.

Comment: what is the size of those stores, especially the database. You should have more ram than the size of your database. But keep in mind Magento has a huge footprint and it is a pain to get it fast.

Comment: Updated the initial quesiton with those details. In summary: 14k products. 9k simple and 5k grouped. The grouped products have the simple products associated to them.

Comment: I'm not familiar with eAccelerator, but it looks like its cache is full.  Increasing its cache size will probably help.  The problem is probably at least partially related to the database; can you post the structure of the tables?

Comment: The database structure remains more or less intact since installation, which you can find [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/2_-_magento_concepts_and_architecture/magento_database_diagram)

Although that's the diagram for the 1.3 magento version, and I'm running 1.7. There's been a number of changes since then but overall it remains basically the same.

I'm running the flat catalog option, that ignores the EAV structure, but that's only for the frontend.

Edit: Found the structure for my specific version: [here](http://www.magereverse.com/index/magento-database-diagram/version/1-7-0-2)

Comment: sounds like the `INSERT` commands are clogging, so with an increased cache and if possible modified INSERT commands `INSERT DELAYED` maybe you could speed things up. Be careful though I have no idea if you need insertIDs or not (don't have any magento); if you do, it will not help even a bit (most likely).

Comment: This question would be better off in http://dba.stackexchange.com/. This being said, have you checked the actual load of the server? (CPU load, memory usage, swap, etc.). I am afraid your PHP limits `memory_limit = 1024M` and `max_execution_time = 18000` are way too high and could easily allow crazy processes to run virtually forever on your server.

Comment: i would suggest to get a pci-e raid card and 2 x SSD. You will pay some money for it but your gain will be enormousness.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The straightforward answer is: **the server is underpowered**. No matter how you configure this, you will need to upgrade for an environment more suited to Magento.

[image: CPU Mark Relative to Top 10 Common CPUs]

Source: http://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu.php?cpu=AMD+Athlon+64+X2+Dual+Core+3400%2B

Mind you though, the CPUs listed above are very high-end CPUs with about 10 times the processing power compared to the AMD dual-core chip. 
My laptop CPU which is an Intel Core i7 2.2GHz quad-core benchmarks at around 5,000. I would recommend that you go for a CPU above 5,000 from the [list found here](http://www.cpubenchmark.net/high_end_cpus.html).

16GB RAM and an SSD would also seem sensible/reasonable given that it does not cost much these days.

Comment: I'm currently in the process of upgrading the server.

The new server will have the following,
CPU: Intel Xeon E3-1230 Quad Core (Scores 8000 on that list)
Memory: 8GB DDR3
Disk: 2x 60Gb SSD (Raid 0)

Do you think it will be enough?

Comment: Yes that sounds like a monster!

Answer (score 3):

Your cache size is way too low for a site like Magento. I run a similar site, and we have 256mb of cache. With 16mb you're going to be running into caching dumps constantly.

Your server resources are fine for the load you have, assuming nothing else huge is running next to Magento. It's a hog, but it's not that bad and 4gb of RAM is more than enough.

I would temporarily disable your cache and see if that improves anything. I'd also recommend that you look through the store configuration in Magento because you may not have the best caching configuration - Magento's caching setup is complex and opaque.

Answer (score 3):

I know this thread is ancient internet time. Just thought I'd add a few points I think are most relevant for most owners / developers. Magento performance can be a deep topic with many things toconsider, but hopefully understanding a few main points will go a long way:

1. **The more you leverage caching** (opcode cache, MySQL cache, full page cache, etc.) **the less important the hardwar**e. It sounds great because the hardware you're currently on is, sorry to say, pretty terrible (as already pointed out). You can get around this and sort of mask the performance issues by better leveraging caching. Most importantly setup full page cache (google) and opcode cache.
2. While caching will help speed things up, **poor hardware will be noticable when you hit non-cached pages** like deeply filtered category pages, search pages, cart, checkout, etc. Basically anything unique. When a visitor hits one of these pages most of your cahces are bypassed and then it comes down to good hardware / well configured setup. At this point it will be apparent that there are performance problems.
3. Generally speaking, **faster CPU (higher GHz) will mean the many many PHP files that comprise Magento (roughly 14,000+) can be processed faster**. PHP is almost always the largest bottleneck.
4. **SSDs will help a little due to lower latency but they really help with larger catalogs** (more products or orders in the system). In this scenario an SSD will typically outperform HDD (even 15k rpm) because the data is spread across a larger section on the drive so it has to bounce around to different physical locations on a hard disk to access the various MySQL tables and access the data. SSDs handle this kind of "random seek" work much better. If you have enough memory to load your entire DB into memory then this doesn't matter much except when writing an order to the database during checkout or product data for a saved cart, etc.
5. **A common misconception is that more CPU cores = faster website**. This is very misleading. Think of a CPU like a major freeway. The cores are like lanes on the freeway and the CPU GHz is like the speed limit. Would you rather have 20 lanes @ 50 mph or 1 lane at 100 mph? Depends on the amount of traffic, right! More concurrent visitors on your site means that more cores will generally help. If you have relatively low traffic, then fewer cores but higher clock speed is much better. Take into consideration that things like the Magento cron, indexer, and admins working in the admin area all add to the load. If you've also added caching programs like redis, memcache, varnish, etc. those also consume some space on the freeway.
6. **A simple way to check if your CPU or HDDs are being overworked would be to check server stats**. Try setting something up like [sar](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sar) that will log cpu / disk stats every 10 minutes for you to review (can customize). You'll want to see the % idle time for the CPU. More idle time = not working too hard. Probably don't need more cores. For disk check the `iowait` column (or use `iostat` in real-time). If you've got a high iowait then maybe better disks or SSDs will help.
7. **The more ram you have = more you can cache (and connections you can handle).** A certain amount of ram is used for each connection from users (apache / nginx / mysql) and for general system overhead. The more ram you have the more things you can cache in ram which is faster. For example, you can tune MySQL and store most of the data in memory so that looking things up is faster. This is because the ram not only has lower latency but also requires less CPU cycles to retrieve data. The result is faster loads (sometimes only marginally) and much lower CPU load. You can store sessions, Magento cache, full page cahces, MySQL data, and other items in memory. So the amount you need may vary but here's a general rule of thumb: the size of your database should only be about 25 - 50% of your memory. If you have a 1 GB magento database, you should have about 4 GB of memory. This obviously changes the more sessions or cached pages etc. you store in memory.
8. **Often a CDN doesn't drastically affect user page loads but more importantly reduces server load.** The main advantage of a CDN is that its servers are physically closer to your visitor for downloading content. When considering a closer server may only shave off 50ms from the load time it's not that big of an impact. More importantly having the CDN handle all the requrests for static files can leave your server to mainly work on dynamic requests. In some cases this means the CDN is handling loading for 90-99% of the assets loaded on a page (images, css, js, etc.). Under traffic spikes / high loads that can be significant.

Comment: As I've commented above, I already upgraded my system, but thanks for taking your time. One can never learn enough and I'm sure others will benefit from your answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

I do web development for a company who handles 30k+ products over 7 sites and we generally try to steer away from using the admin for uploads / edit products. We use [magmi](http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/) for uploads and edits. We are very happy with this product.
Are you using a ligtspeed server?

Comment: No, it's a plain apache 2.0 running mpm_worker and mpm_prefork.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running a virtual server, possibly look at using Nginx as an Apache replacement. I have found this can give some performance boosts. Also look in to implementing some kind of caching. I would recommend using Memcached or Redis (if you can get it running). This will undoubtably give you big performance gains.

Magento is a very database intensive system. Depending on how busy you website is you could possibly add some more ram so ensure you have enough memory for the amount of processes being run.

Answer (score 0):

Magento require a lot of resource. Backend structure is something kind of slow and hard to optimize. But I suggest import all product from csv/xml and not do it by hand. You'll find lots of tutorial on this.

To optimize frontend, here are some tips :

- Refer to GTMetrix to have metrics of your performance : http://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.belexpress.eu/k2bPETVr your homepage is too big. A page shouldn't go over 1MB at first load. You should use lazy load, optimize image, etc. to have this faster.
- Some tips allow to have very very better performance, but you'll need a bigger server, if your website generate traffic and you're able to get $500 per month for hosting you can find very powerful server configuration like 6 Quad Core, 48GB RAM, SSD disks, 10GB/s network with unlimited bandwidth.
- If you choose a better hosting solution (with a more powerful server) you can gain performance by mouting as RAM the most used directories, like /var and /include/src if you use the compilation. Use compilation only if you don't make daily changes on your code, if you don't, compiling + mounting /include/src as RAM will give you very good performance gain.
- I don't know well eAccelerator and memcached, personnaly I use APC and I replaced port 80 with Varnish. That gives extra speed to my websites.

Having Magento run fast is an everyday work to optimize every aspects, there is no magic tricks.

Regards,

Comment: There's no way he needs a 24 core, 48gb ram setup to run three stores with less than 5k products.

Comment: it's an example, if your website handle 100 orders per day and generate $10k per day why can't you get a very big server ?
For 5k product and 3 store I suggest at least 2 quad core and 12GB RAM for mouting hd as RAM

Comment: Because the issue is clearly not capacity. Due to that, it's not entirely evident that a more powerful server would make things any faster - if the issue is, for example, constant cache dumps than the cache misconfiguration will be an issue with 256mb of ram or 64gb of ram.

Comment: you are right. +1. Except for some rare case, hardware have to be the very last optimization. But to allow some powerful things he needs a better server.

Answer (score 0):

If you are done with development, I would disable slow query logging on mysql (lines copied from your my.cnf):

```
log_slow_queries        = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time = 2
```

You didn't post your .htaccess file, where some php and apache settings can be overridden.

Have you added cache settings to your /app/etc/local.xml? If not, take a look at /app/etc/local.xml.additional and apply what best suits you.